# Opposite PHP function of strstr to return first part of string, not last

Tags: php, string, strstr

I have an string, something like this:

```
$abcdef(+$1.00)
```

I'm trying to get the first part of the string before the first parenthesis:

```
$abcdef
```

Currently if I use `strstr()` it will return the part of the string after the specified character:

```
$newstr = strstr($var, '(');
```

I want the part before the occurrence. What is the reverse or opposite function of [strstr()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) that will do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pass true as the third parameter.

From the [manual page you have linked](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php):

```
string strstr (string $haystack , mixed $needle [, bool $before_needle = false ])
```

> **before_needle**: If TRUE, strstr() returns the part of the haystack
>   before the first occurrence of the needle (excluding the needle).

**Note:** This parameter was only added in PHP 5.3. If for some reason you are left with an older version, a combination of `substr()` and `strpos()` should help:

```
$newstr = substr( $var, 0, strpos( $var, '(' ) );
```

Comment: Is that all I had to do?!? Thanks @bažmegakapa

Answer (score 4):

Set third parameter of strstr to true it will return occurrence before needle

Answer (score 0):

Better method to do this in a simple way is:

$newstr = explode('(',$var)[0];

Explanation:
$result = explode('search_for_this' , $search_in_this)[0];