# strstr returns blank line instead of first part of string

Tags: php, concatenation, strstr

I am trying to concatenate a field from an RSS feed in WordPress. An example line of data is:

```
The Scala in London, - David Ford is touring the UK in support of his brand new 
album, 'Charge', released in March 2013
```

It displays using this code:

```
<?php echo esc_html( $item->get_description() ); ?>
```

I want it to stop just before the `,` - therefore displaying "The Scala in London"

I have used this code in place of the above code:

```
<?php echo strstr($item->get_description, "-"); ?>
```

However it just returns a blank line. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP string function - the opposite of strstr](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10707113/php-string-function-the-opposite-of-strstr)

Comment: Should `echo strstr($item->get_description, "-");` be `echo strstr($item->get_description(), ",", true);` ?

Comment: Almost - that shows everything AFTER the "," but I want everything BEFORE the ","!